# Changing footnote numbering numbers to Hindi (Arabic) with left-to-right text

Tags: microsoft-word, footnote

I have a question regarding footnote numbering format in Word 2013. I want the footnote numbering format to be Hindi (Arabic) while the footnote text to be left to right.

How can I make the change for all footnotes simultaneously?

Comment: It'd be good if you could show an example of what you want to achieve.

Comment: See [this post](https://superuser.com/questions/182039/how-to-change-some-of-the-numbers-in-word-to-be-arabic-numbers-within-word).